# Чи можуть огірки бути "соленими"?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

Працюючи із німецьким текстом, одне із словосполучень я переклав як "солені палички", однак викладачка пізніше виправила "солені" на "солоні" і, на жаль, я не мав змоги спитатися чому так.

Першим ділом я заглянув до СУМу, де знайшов визначення як [одного](http://sum.in.ua/s/solonyj), так і [другого](http://sum.in.ua/s/solenyj) слова, і ось, що я там побачив:

> **Солоний** - приправлений сіллю, із характерним смаком, що його надає
>   сіль (про їжу).

А от "солений" - це той, що приготовлений солінням (наприклад, солені огірки). Підтверджують це й інші джерела, наприклад, «Словник-довідник з українського літературного слововживання» С. І. Головащука ([1](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53409/32219.html), [2](http://hohlopedia.org.ua/literaturne_slovovjyvannya/page/solonyy_solenyy.2331/)).

Хоча, для мене ця інформація здалася дивною, тому що у мене вдома (Галичина) люди кажуть, що страва - солена, а от огірки (ті, які закриваються в банці), наприклад, - солоні (та й судячи із статті на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8), не лише у мене вдома так кажуть).

Тому у мене виникло питання чи не можуть ці слова бути синонімами? Пошуки в [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), не дали ніякого результату. Крім того я ще знайшов рецепт "[соленого печива](http://panistefa.com/solene-pechyvo-i-soleni-palychky-z-kmynom/)", але гадаю, що цей сайт не є надійним джерелом.

Отож, чи можуть ці слова інколи заміняти один одного? І чи казати "солоні огірки"/"солені палички" - це помилка?

Comment: думаю, це слова зі значеннями, що частково перекриваються; причому спектр значень кожного з цих слів, можливо, ще й залежить від мовця/діалекту (припускаю, що може виявитися так, що те, що для одного _солене_, для іншого _солоне_)

Comment: _солоні огірки_ точно не помилка, бо є в СУМ-11 (4-е значення слова _солоний_) — і в корпусі GRAC-3 трапляється в 17 разів частіше за _солені огірки_

Comment: Прошу звернути увагу на те, що солоний - прикметник, а от солений - дієприкметник від слова "солити". Вода в морі - солона - це її характеристика, страва - зазвичай не буде солена, якщо не посолиш. Огірки солоні не тому, що ми їх солимо, свою соленість вони набирають із маринаду... і т.д.